# How to get rid of thin diameter line showing up on my pure CSS spinner (Firefox only)

Tags: css, firefox, mask

I'm using the following pure CSS spinner (see below), it is good for me because it's center is transparent and works on all backgrounds, and it only needs one HTML element. On Firefox browser I get a thin diameter line, how can I remove it?
[image: see the line here]

```css
.css-loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: calc(50% - 55px);
  left: calc(50% - 55px);
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation: loader-spin 1s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #f5854c) 0 0/50% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  --mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - 16px - .5px), #000 calc(100% - 16px + .5px));
  mask: var(--mask);
}

@keyframes loader-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [conic gradient](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#conic-gradients) instead. A conic gradient looks better because the direction of the gradient is truly **around** the edge of the semicircle, and it is much easier to make adjustments to the gradient to achieve different effects. It avoids the ugly/tricky background truncation which is needed to make the linear gradient work as a spinner, and which doesn’t always perfectly mesh with the masking, as you found happens in Firefox. The mask can also be simplified.

```
background: conic-gradient(transparent 180deg, #f5854c 360deg);
--mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 75%, black 75%);
```

180-360deg[image: semicircular spinner created with conic gradient 180-360deg]

You can adjust the color stops as desired. I prefer the spinner as a full circle rather than a semicircle (starting at `0deg` instead of `180deg`). I also prefer the final stop position being three quarters of the way around the circle (at `270deg` instead of `360deg`) — this makes the spinner appear darker and stronger.

```
background: conic-gradient(transparent 0deg, #f5854c 270deg);
```

0-360deg [image: full circle spinner created with conic gradient 0-360deg]
0-270deg [image: full circle spinner created with conic gradient 0-270deg]

```css
.css-loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: calc(50% - 55px);
  left: calc(50% - 55px);
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation: loader-spin 1s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(transparent 0deg, #f5854c 270deg);
  --mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 75%, black 75%);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
}

@keyframes loader-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-loader"></div>
```